# Azure Digital Twin RoleAssignment permissions

Tags: azure-digital-twins

I have assigned SpaceAdministrator Role level for the Azure Ad UserID using the postman call for the API end point https://xxxxxx.eastus.azuresmartspaces.net/management/api/v1.0/roleassignments which was successfull.

Postman call:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX92t.png)

Later when we tried validating the roles permissions using the API endpoint
https://xxxx.eastus.azuresmartspaces.net/management/api/v1.0/roleassignments/check?path=/&userId=xxxxx-cab9-4ac3-b4ec-60bc4236fc47&accessType=Read&resourceType=Space   it always return false and we are unable to validate the role permissions

Comment: When testing from here you also see false as result? https://docs.westcentralus.azuresmartspaces.net/management/swagger/ui/index#/RoleAssignments/RoleAssignments_Check

Comment: Yes, i am seeing false that is what is my i am not sure what we are missing which is causing. Are you able to validate the permissions? If yes can you share the details how are implementing. Also is there possibility to implement custom roles.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to specify the `tenantId` in the check access query.

For example:

> https://xxxx.eastus.azuresmartspaces.net/management/api/v1.0/roleassignments/check?path=/&userId=xxxxx-cab9-4ac3-b4ec-60bc4236fc47&accessType=Read&resourceType=Space**&tenantId={tenantIdGuid}**